не импортируется executor из библиотеки aiogram 3
написал код, но он не стартуется из-за ошибки. начало кода:
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram import executor
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent

после запуска в терминале появляется ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'
предпринимал: переустанавливал библиотеки различными способами. не помогло

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ===> какая версия aiogram используется, полное сообщение об ошибке, и какой код используется.Объясните, что уже было предпринято для решения проблемы

В Aiogram 3.x executor был выведен. Попробуй откатить Aiogram до версии <=2.25.1
pip uninstall aiogram && pip install aiogram==2.25.1

